# how to handle StreamBuilder listening to non-existent snapshot?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

all i want to achieve is as long as the document exists in cloud firestore....my streambuilder keeps listening to its snapshots...if for some reason..the document has been removed from cloud firestore collection, i want to `Navigator.of(context).pop()` safely without any errors.

this is my StreamBuilder right now:

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .document(widget.passedPostId)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

 if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor:
                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
          );
        }

        String postTitle = snapshot.data['postTitle'];
        String postBody = snapshot.data['postBody'];


        return Container(child: Column(children:[
          Text('$postTitle'),
          Text('$postBody'),

       ]));



      }
    );
```

from this point, everything works well as intended, but when i open the cloud firestore collection and manually delete the document from the collection...the App crashes and i get this error:

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("postTitle")
```

so to recap:

**i want to delete the document from cloud firestore collection manually...and the App safely determines that the document doesn't exist anymore...so it `Navigator.of(context).pop()` the current screen**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilising `exists` property on `DocumentSnapshot`.

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return LoadingWidget();
}

if (!snapshot.data.exists) {
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  });
  return SizedBox();
}

return DataWidget();
```

The `Future` is a hack required to execute `pop` after building is complete. Alternatively you can use `SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback` which will produce the same result.